# How do you POST files in chunks, to server, using input id as param, in HTML/jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, post

### Description

I have a function that takes **HTTP_POST path** for server side hardcoded .js handler and **file id from input[type=file]**. I'm trying to POST that *binary* file to server but in chunks with no success.

### What have you tried?

Using my [uncle](https://www.google.com/) wisdom, I have noted that there is a way to slice the file using :

```
var File1 = document.querySelector('input').files[0].slice(0,7);
```

But passing this variable to the function is not an option since it takes **`id ="file_1"`** as a parameter from **`<input type="file">`**. Also, printing this variable doesn't work with `console.log` (half of you are already thinking to send me back to uni) *hint: I've never studied Javascript*. So I poked my uncle a little harder and found [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). FileReader gives you the ability to actually read the inside, which gave me hope since my file was printed out to `console.log`

```
var reader = new FileReader;
reader.readAsBinaryString(File1);
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var rawLog = reader.result;
    console.log(rawLog);
};
```

At this point `console.log` gave me a print of first seven bytes, of my file. And by all of this we got to the question I wish to ask

### Question ?¿

How to past this print as with `input` to the function so I can have this file sliced and saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice off a piece of the file, use that piece to create a File object add it to a FileList and then overwrite the FileList from the input with the one that has your new file

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var originalfile = input.files[0];
var slice = originalfile.slice(0,7); // slice the file
var newfile = new File([slice] , 'slicedfile.dat'); // create new file
// Need to use a data transfer object to get a new FileList object
var datTran = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer(); 
datTran.items.add(newfile);  // Add the file to the DT object
input.files = datTran.files; // overwrite the input file list with ours
// call function that takes path and id as parameters
```

Comment: Failed to construct 'File': The object must have a callable @@iterator property.
Uncle again saved the day : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/357#:~:text=Oh%2C%20btw%20you%20have%20to%20use%20an%20array%20in%20the%20File%20constructor%20as%20well