# Why <input type="file"> return 0 bytes after input.files overwrite?

Tags: html, jquery, post

### Description

I have a function that takes **HTTP_POST path** for server side hardcoded .js handler and **file id from input[type=file]**. I'm trying to POST that *binary* file to server but in chunks with success but just for one function call. After I tried to call this function several times I got to the point that I'm not sure how to handle the scenario.

### What have you tried?

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561659/how-do-you-post-files-in-chunks-to-server-using-input-id-as-param-in-html-jqu) I made on click event that should start transfer the files after slicing them.

```
    $("#btn_upload").on("click", function () {
        var input = document.querySelector('input');
        var originalfile = input.files[0];

        var headerFile1 = originalfile.slice(0,7);
        var headerFile2 = originalfile.slice(7,14);

        var header1 = headerFile1.text();

        var file1 = originalfile.slice(14,header1+14);
        var file2 = originalfile.slice(header1+14,);

        var newfile1 = new File([file1] , 'bin1.bin');
        var newfile2 = new File([file2] , 'bin2.bin');

        var datTran = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer();

        datTran.items.add(newfile1);
        datTran.items.add(newfile2);
        input.files = datTran.files;

        uploadFile('POST_PATH', 'input');
    }
```

### Question ?¿

- Why I'm receiving 0 bytes on server side?
- How it should be handled?
- Is there a way to manage this with multiple files using [`.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

Comment: I can give you a working example if you want to use the [dropzonejs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) extension.

Comment: I managed to do it in interval loops but its not elegant. Show me this dropzonejs thingy, maybe its good for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. Here is a working demo part from my code which may be able to help you resolve your problem. If you want to do more than this, you can find the documentation [here](https://www.dropzonejs.com/). It can happen that some part is not relevant for you, just skip that part.

If you have any questions regarding to this, feel free to ask!

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$().ready(function(){
  $("#upload").unbind().click(() => {
      $("#fileUploadWindow").modal("show")
      generateDropzone()
  })
})

function generateDropzone() {
        $("#fileUploadWindow").modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
            url: "/Home/UploadFiles",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            dictInvalidFileType: "",
            dictUploadCanceled: "",
            dictRemoveFile: "Remove",
            maxFiles: 6,
            maxfilesexceeded: function (file) { alert("Max 6!"); this.removeFile(file) },
            maxFilesize: 100,
            acceptedFiles: "image/*, video/*",
            success: function (file, response) {
                $("#fileUploadWindow").modal("hide");
                this.destroy();
            },
            error: function (file, response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
            init: function () {
                
                var dp = this;

                $("#upload-button").unbind().click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    dp.processQueue();
                });

                $("#close-button").unbind().click(function (e) {
                    $("#fileUploadWindow").modal("hide")
                    e.preventDefault();
                    dp.destroy();
                });

                this.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
                    var data = $('#frmTarget').serializeArray();
                    $.each(data, function (key, el) {
                        formData.append(el.name, el.value);
                    });
                });

                this.on("error", function (file) {
                    if (!file.accepted) {
                        this.removeFile(file);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
#dZUpload {
     background: white;
     border-radius: 5px;
     border: 2px dashed gray !important;
     border-image: none;
     max-width: 500px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
}
 #dZUpload .dz-message {
     margin-top: 2.5em !important;
   margin-bottom: 2.5em !important;
}
 #dZUpload .dz-success-mark {
     margin-top: 0px !important;
   display: none;
}
 #dZUpload .dz-max-files-reached, #dZUpload .dz-error-message, #dZUpload .dz-success-mark, #dZUpload .dz-error-mark, #dZUpload .dz-filename, #dZUpload .dz-size  {
     display: none !important;
}

#dZUpload .dz-preview {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

 #upload {
     margin-top: 15px;
     height: 50px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     width: 200px;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     font-family: 'Open Sans Regular';
     font-weight: 500;
     background-color: transparent;
     transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
     border-radius: 2.5px;
     text-align: center;
}
 #upload span:first-child {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     margin-top: 12px;
     display: block;
}
 #upload:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: lightgray;
     transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
 #upload:hover span {
     color: white;
}
 #fileUploadWindow .btn-primary, #colorpickerWindow .btn-primary, #urlWindow .btn-primary, #fileUploadWindow .btn-secondary, #colorpickerWindow .btn-secondary, #urlWindow .btn-secondary {
     background-color: transparent;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     color: black;
     font-family: 'Open Sans SemiBold';
     font-size: 15px;
     border-radius: 2.5px;
}
 #fileUploadWindow .btn-primary:hover, #colorpickerWindow .btn-primary:hover, #urlWindow .btn-primary:hover, #fileUploadWindow .btn-secondary:hover, #colorpickerWindow .btn-secondary:hover, #urlWindow .btn-secondary:hover {
     background-color: gray;
     color: white;
}
 .modal-dialog {
     max-width: 600px;
}
 .modal-content {
     border-radius: 8px;
     box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px #b3b3b3;
     background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
 .modal-header {
     display: block !important;
     text-align: center !important;
}
 .modal-header .header-title {
     min-width: 100%;
}
 .modal-header .header-title h5 {
     margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
 .modal-header .header-info, .modal-header .header-info div {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-style: italic;
}
 .modal-header .float-right {
     float: right !important;
     text-align: right !important;
}
 .modal-header .float-left {
     float: left !important;
     text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.2/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>


<div id="upload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fileUploadWindow">
    <span>
        Upload
    </span>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="fileUploadWindow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content text-center">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="header-title"><h5>Uploading files</h5></div>
                <div class="header-info mt-3">
                    <div>You can upload 6 files at once!</div>
                    <div>Max size: 100MB!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone">
                        <div class="dz-default dz-message">Drag here or click to browse!</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="upload-button" class="btn btn-secondary">Upload</button>
                    <button type="button" id="close-button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```